# How to answer to tens of emails with the same template in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Sometimes in Thunderbird I get 10 or 20 emails per day to which I always answer the same. I was thinking about creating some template for them, but instead of replying that template on a per single email basis, trying to apply the template to all those emails at the same time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to create a signature containing your canned answer. That way when you have to reply, you simply select that signature and send it on its way.

There is not a way to send the same answer as a reply to multiple emails at once because each email you receive is unique,  and goes to a different address.